# List a CMake file

Tags: listings, highlighting

Does anyone have/know of a style file for the listings package which would enable the correct syntax highlighting of `cmake` files in LaTeX?

Comment: The `minted` manual says it supports all languages that `Pygments` does, which includes CMake. I know this doesn't answer the question, just pointing out an alternative.

Comment: As @Psirus mentioned, you can try `minted`. If you are not satisfied and want to try it out with `listings` then try to copy the style of the one `minted` outputs into your `listings` `cmake` language environment with your own modifications.

Comment: What you mean by "correct syntax highlighting" is unclear? What output would you like to obtain? An MWE and a list of specs would help...

Answer (score 6):

This does not answer your question specifically, but it is possible to pretty print CMake lists using the `minted` package. Here an example using the `CMakeLists.txt` from the [Lua Programming Language](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{cmake}{CMakeLists.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMake Example]